# Who is the Dragon God Lamya?

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

The Heroes VI Collectors Ed has a Dragon god Lamya T-shirt included. Who is this Lamya? AFAIK, there's only Asha, Urgash, Elrath, Sylanna, Malassa, Shalassa, Ylath, Arkath and Sandro (if he counted as one), but no Lamya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lamya is a shadow dragon. It is expected to be the final boss.

[image: Lamya]

[Source](http://heroescommunity.com/viewthread.php3?TID=33727&pagenumber=462)

Comment: The game is released.  Shouldn't we know one way or the other now?

Comment: @bwarner...you are correct on the release